# Remove Decimal in Set Product Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am new in Magento and I can't find the solution to remove the decimal values in the standard number in Set/Bundle Products in the Admin Panel. I used ET Currency manager but it only affects the prices in the admin panel. I am using magento 1.9.3

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Because it is unnecessary.

Comment: That's very precise reply. Good luck.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Sorry if I sounded rude. But I need to remove ALL the decimal in the admin panel from prices to this because it is unnecessary.

Comment: New to Magento?  Leave it alone.  I hate to say that, but you're going to be better off, imho.  I would hope that you could consider modifying frontend templates to output an integer for visual purpose only -- if that's what would suit the real issue...

Comment: I think this requirement is unnecessary cos its going to handled by owners not the website users

Comment: @df2k2 there is no problem in frontend because it is showing it without decimal. Only in Admin Panel.

Comment: @mujas I think so too. But I was instructed to remove it.